# deleting comments or likes by id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I am new to loopback nodejs services. I saw that it generates an angular sdk based on models.

I am looking at the explorer and see a method to deleteAll but do not see how to delete by ID.

I have a relationship set up so that each activity has many comments.

Angularjs SDK does not have a method that states deleteById for hasMany relationships.

Wondering what is the equivalent of mongoose's $pull from an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to delete a Comment belonging to an Activity and that the `hasMany` relationship is set up with foreign key `activityId`.

To disassociate the Comment from the Activity:

```
comment = // an instance of Comment model
delete comment.activityId;
comment.$save();
```

To remove the comment from the database:

```
comment = // an instance of Comment model
Comment.deleteById({ id: comment.id });
```

Angular's built-in `$remove` method should work too:

```
comment = // an instance of Comment model
comment.$remove();
```

See also [ngResource.$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) docs.

Answer (score 1):

It's discussed in more detail here.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/EKRKhUHo3KQ